# Drop down selection using cookie value ID

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-chosen

I'm attempting to automatically populate a dropdown selection using the value stored in a cookie, however I'm not having much luck getting this to work.

I have a cookie called `affwp_ref` which stores an ID e.g. `1`. This relates to a name in the DB.

I have a dropdown using the Chosen library on my page as highlighted below. I'd like to take the value from the cookie, e.g. `1`, and then use this to select the item in the dropdown so that `Item1` would be selected.

If the cookie is empty I'd like to default to `Please make a selection`.

```html
<ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Select a cause</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Item1</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Item2</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Item3</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the JS? We can't really help you debug the logic without seeing it

Comment: Here is my initial JS @RoryMcCrossan


if($.cookie('affwp_ref') != null) {

    $('.chosen-select[data-option-array-index="' + $.cookie('affwp_ref') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger("chosen:updated");

}

$('.chosen-select').change(function() {

    $.cookie('affwp_ref', $('.select_class option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});

});